# Phonegap android - how to open native contacts list?

Tags: cordova

So I'm building app for android using phonegap 2.7 I need on click open native contact list, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [ContactPicker](https://github.com/hazemhagrass/ContactPicker) plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Contacts](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts) of phonegap